# How does one align text to the top, center part in a UITableViewCell (In Swift 5)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, swift5

I understand this code can align the text of a UITableViewCell to the center:

```
cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
```

However, I need to align it to the top of the same cell, and also center it. How can I achieve this? UIEdgeContentInsets? Bit confused and I need help. Thanks!

Example, would be something like;

`cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .topCenter`

**Note;** previous line doesn't actually exist as a way to place it in the top center of the cell. But, I am thinking there has to be a way apple provides to do this.

I've read through docs can't find anything -_-. Does anyone have any custom solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Labels do not do vertical alignment; they are vertically *centered* only. If you don't like that, move the label, or allow its height to fit its contents, or don't use a label.

Comment: Wow you have a great reputation here, makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You could create a Custom TableView Cell & use it:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. This helps a lot. If I want this particular, custom cell to be a different height than the other cells in the tableview, what would I do?

Comment: If you want the height to be fixed, then return height from tableview delegate method func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) or if you want the height to be dynamic which means content can be very big, multiple line, first put a bottom constraints of that label, set number of line is 0 for the label, then return UITableView.automaticDimension from the same method instead of fixed height.